# ArgoCD Application Set merge generator

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I have an argocd ApplicationSet created. I have the following merge keys setup:

```
    generators:
      - merge:
          mergeKeys:
            - path
          generators:
            - matrix:
                generators:
                  - git:
                      directories:
                        - path: aws-ebs-csi-driver
                        - path: cluster-autoscaler
                      repoURL: >-
                        ...
                      revision: master
                  - clusters:
                      selector:
                        matchLabels:
                          argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: cluster
            - list:
                elements:
                  - path: aws-ebs-csi-driver
                    namespace: system
                  - path: cluster-autoscaler
                    namespace: system
```

Syncing the application set however generates:

```
    - lastTransitionTime: "2022-08-08T21:54:05Z"
      message: the parameters from a generator were not unique by the given mergeKeys,
        Merge requires all param sets to be unique. Duplicate key was {"path":"aws-ebs-csi-driver"}
      reason: ApplicationGenerationFromParamsError
      status: "True"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix generator is producing one set of parameters for each combination of directory and cluster.

If there is more than one cluster, then there will be one parameter set with `path: aws-ebs-csi-driver` for each cluster.

The merge generator requires that each parameter used as a merge key be completely unique. That mode was the original design of the merge generator, but more modes may be supported in the future.

Argo CD v2.5 will support [go templated ApplicationSets](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operator-manual/applicationset/GoTemplate/), which might provide an easier way to solve your problem.